# Python::check if the list contains item and also the pattern at another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let say I have this list:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, d]    
yes_i_have = [b,c]    
pattern_not_match = [c,b]
```

How do I check the list contains item and also the pattern at another list??

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: boolean output will be fine!

Comment: is [b,d] matching or no?

Comment: @XinHuang i need [b,d] is not matching

Comment: How is it that you don't know how to check whether the list contains given items?  That is documented quite well on line.  For the pattern, use list slicing to walk through 2-element slices of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
yes = [2, 3]
no = [3, 2]
yes in mylist  # False
tuple(yes) in zip(mylist[:], mylist[1:])  # True
tuple(no) in zip(mylist[:], mylist[1:])   # False
```

Edit, as a function:

```
def find(l, x):
    return tuple(x) in zip(*[l[i:] for i in range(len(x))])

find(mylist, yes)  # True
find(mylist, no)   # False
```